# How to Add Array Button with PyQt5 in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sqlite, button, pyqt5

In code below, I want create button array with names and get button name after click, where `users.get_profiles()` Get the Users Value from SQLite3 Database

```
x=0
y=10
move_x=x
move_y=y


for profile in users.get_profiles():
    self.btnUser = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    if move_x>=(145*3):
        move_y=move_y+145
        x=0
    move_x=(10+(145*x))
                    
    self.btnUser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(move_x, move_y, 140, 140))
    self.btnUser.setObjectName(str(profile[0]))
    self.btnUser.setStyleSheet("text-align:center;")
    self.btnUser.setText(str(profile[1]))
    self.btnUser.clicked.connect(self.users_btn)
    x+=1
```

Comment: If you want to get the button that called the function when clicked, use `self.sender()` in that function. Note that setting an instance attribute in a for loop is pointless. Also, setting fixed geometries is always discouraged, and you should use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.